# Deleting Highcharts organization chart selected node

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have created a chart using Highcharts organization chart with PHP and MySQL as follow`

```js
let selectedNode = undefined;
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        height: "40%",
        inverted: true
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'EA Organogram'
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'organization',
        name: 'Employee Name',
        keys: ['from', 'to'],
        data: [["manager", "employee1"], ["manager", "employee2"], ["manager", "employee3"], ["manager", "employee4"],
            ["employee2", "employee5"], ["employee2", "employee6"]
        ],
        colorByPoint: false,
        color: '#bed308',
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'black'
        },
        borderColor: 'black',
        nodeWidth: 65,

    }],
    tooltip: {
        outside: true
    },
    exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 800,
        sourceHeight:600
    },
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            allowPointSelect: true,
            point:{
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events:{
                    select: function (event) {
                        console.log("selected");

                        if(selectedNode !== undefined &&
                            selectedNode.selected &&
                            selectedNode !== this ){
                            selectedNode.select();
                        }

                        selectedNode = this;
                    },
                    unselect: function (event) {
                        selectedNode = undefined;
                        console.log("unselected");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#delNode').on('click', function(){

    if(selectedNode === undefined){
        alert("Select a node!");
    }else{
        selectedNode.remove();
        chart.series[0].update();
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Organogram</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <div>
          <div id="container">
          </div>
          <button type="button" id="delNode">Delete node</button>
      </div>
    
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/organization.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

what I want is to delete the selected node, but when the button is clicked the most lower end node is deleted. As this question was answered in highcharts forum, but that chart also has this problem. don't know what is the issue

Comment: sorry forgot to add jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/hredq612/

Comment: You can try this approach - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jLse56yu/ However I am not sure what should happen in your case when the `employee2` node will be removed?

Comment: Thanks it is working, but when you export the chart you see that the changes have not affected the chart

Comment: in this case, try to use this kind of solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q5btrkmo/

Comment: Dear Sebastian if you notice the line remains after deleting the node

Comment: Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y5wxhc9o/

Comment: thanks very much that is what I am looking for